# Problemas al enviar formulario con jquery y validarlo

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un formulario y estoy incluyendo cada parte con php y validando el formulario con una libreria de jquery este es el link [Jquery validation](http://Jquery%20validation), valido el formulario y muestro el siguiente pero en el siguiente formulario despues de validar no puedo mostrar la siguiente parte aqui les dejo el codigo:

```
<form id="publica-form">
    <div id="contenido1">
        <?php include_once 'views/modules/publicacion/info-general.php'; ?>
    </div>
    <div id="contenido2" style="display: none;">
        <?php include_once "views/modules/publicacion/info-establecimiento.php"; ?>
    </div>
    <div id="contenido3" style="display: none;">
        <?php include_once "views/modules/publicacion/info-distprecio.php"; ?>
    </div>
    <div id="contenido4" style="display: none;">
        <?php include_once 'views/modules/publicacion/info-servicios.php'; ?>
    </div>
    <div id="contenido5" style="display: none;">
        <?php include_once 'views/modules/publicacion/info-fotos.php'; ?>
    </div>
    <div id="contenido6" style="display: none;">
        <?php include_once 'views/modules/publicacion/info-condiciones.php'; ?>
    </div>
</form>
```

La idea seria que se muestre el siguiente contenido cada vez que se valida. este seria el codigo de jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
$("#next1").click(function(event) {

$("#publica-form").validate({
   rules: {
  nombre_alojamiento: "required",
     tipo_alojamiento: "required",
     numero_hab: {
      required: true,
      min: 1,
      number: true
     },
     nombre_contacto: "required",
     numero_principal: "required",
     direccion_1: "required",
     direccion_2: "required",
     pais_region: "required",
     ciudad: "required",
     codigo_postal: "required"
   },
   messages: {
     nombre_alojamiento: "Ingresa el nombre de tu alojamiento",
     tipo_alojamiento: "Selecciona unas de las opciones",
     numero_hab: {
      required: "Ingresa el número de habitaciones",
      min: jQuery.validator.format("Ingresa un número mayor o igual a {0}"),
      number: "Solamente números admitidos"
     },
     nombre_contacto: "Ingrese un nombre de contacto",
     numero_principal: "Ingrese un número de contacto",
     direccion_1: "Ingrese una dirección",
     direccion_2: "Ingrese una Avenida, edificio, etc",
     pais_region: "Por favor selecciona una opción",
     ciudad: "Ingresa la ciudad del establecimiento",
     codigo_postal: "Ingresa el codigo postal del establecimiento"
 },
 errorElement: "p",
 submitHandler: function(form) { 
  $("#contenido1").css("display", "none");
     $("#contenido2").css("display", "block");
  }
 });
  });
```

en el siguiente hago lo mismo el boton id="next2" pero no me muestra el #contenido3 ni me oculta el #contenido2 este seria el codigo:

```js
$("#next2").click(function(event) {
 /* Act on the event */
 $("#publica-form").validate({
  rules: {
   entrada_desde: "required",
   entrada_hasta: "required",
   salida_desde: "required",
   salida_hasta: "required",
   internet: "required",
   aparcamiento: "required",
   desayuno: "required",
   ninos: "required",
   idioma: "required"
  },
  messages: {
   entrada_desde: "Por favor ingresa desde que hora es la entrada",
   entrada_hasta: "Por favor ingresa hasta que hora es la entrada",
   salida_desde: "Por favor ingresa desde que hora es la salida",
   salida_hasta: "Por favor ingresa hasta que hora es la salida",
   internet: "Por favor indicanos si hay conexion a internet",
   aparcamiento: "Por favor indicanos si hay disponibilidad de aparcamiento",
   desayuno: "Indica si hay desayuno disponible para los clientes",
   ninos: "Indicanos si se pueden alojar niños en el alojamiento",
   idioma: "Indicanos que idioma habla el personal"
  },
  errorElement: "p",
  submitHandler: function(form2) {

    var button2 = $("button[id='next2']");
    $.ajax({
     beforeSend: function(){
       $(button2).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
             $(button2).text('Cargando').append(' <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>');
      },
    })
    .done(function() {
     $("#contenido2").css("display", "none");
     $("#contenido3").css("display", "block");
  
     console.log("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {

     console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
               $(button2).removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled').text('Continuar');
            }, 1500);
     console.log("complete");
    });
     }

 }); 
});
```

Comment: verificas que entra a la parte "done" del ajax de la segunda parte? donde tienes el console.log("success")

Comment: si entra porque la consola me muestra el success, creo que el problema esta en el submitHandler, no pueden haber dos. pero no se como validar si es un solo formulario

Comment: esto es practicamente lo que quiero hacer https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/multipart/

Comment: Cambia $("#publica-form").validate; es decir que cada FORM tenga su ID, porque estas validando lo mismo del paso 1 en cada paso.